# non-zero solution to a complex-valued homogeneous linear system under hermitean constraints

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve a linear system of the form Ax=0 with very specific constraints.
The n×n Matrix A has hermitean symmetry, in the sense of A[i,j]=A*[j,i] as well as a Toeplitz structure A[i,j]=A[i+1,j+1].
The solution n-vector x should be hermitean as well, in the sense of x[i]=x*[-i] (x[i]=x[n-i]).

I already tried some standard methods like scipy.linalg.null_space, but none of them resulted in a satisfiying solution, most of them I no solution at all. Some suggest to take the eigenvector to the smallest eigenvalue, but for the example matrix below, this doesn't even come close to a solution.

This is an example for the type of matrix I mean.

```py
[[ 0.00-0.j   -2.71+0.04j -3.83+2.89j  5.30-3.96j -2.16-0.33j]
 [-2.71-0.04j  0.00-0.j   -2.71+0.04j -3.83+2.89j  5.30-3.96j]
 [-3.83-2.89j -2.71-0.04j  0.00-0.j   -2.71+0.04j -3.83+2.89j]
 [ 5.30+3.96j -3.83-2.89j -2.71-0.04j  0.00-0.j   -2.71+0.04j]
 [-2.16+0.33j  5.30+3.96j -3.83-2.89j -2.71-0.04j  0.00-0.j  ]]
```

This problem occurs in signal processing and an *exact* solution is needed to proceed with the algorithm this is part of. I am thankful for hints, ideas and solutions of any kind.

Comment: *"... but none of them resulted in a satisfiying solution..."*  What does that mean?  Why were the solutions not satisfactory?  *"...an exact solution is needed..."*  With floating point calculations, it is unlikely that you will get an *exact* solution.  (Are you even sure that the coefficients in the matrix are "exact"?)  You'll have to decide how much error is tolerable.

Comment: FYI: Your example matrix is nonsingular, so the only solution to Ax=0 is x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0].

Comment: I agree 100% with Warren's comments. If the matrix is non-singular (in principle or numerically), you would not have a non-trivial solution. Just in case, this question with a bit more clarifications (as per @Warren's comments) would be on-topic at [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) where it might receive more attention.